# Как распарсить следующий XML?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Есть XML файл:

```
<ValCurs Date="01.05.2021" name="Foreign Currency Market">
   <Valute ID="R01010">
      <NumCode>036</NumCode>
      <CharCode>AUD</CharCode>
      <Nominal>1</Nominal>
      <Name>Австралийский доллар</Name>
      <Value>58,1546</Value>
   </Valute>
   <Valute ID="R01020A">
      <NumCode>944</NumCode>
      <CharCode>AZN</CharCode>
      <Nominal>1</Nominal>
      <Name>Азербайджанский манат</Name>
      <Value>44,0524</Value>
   </Valute>
      <Valute ID="R01035">
      <NumCode>826</NumCode>
      <CharCode>GBP</CharCode>
      <Nominal>1</Nominal>
      <Name>Фунт стерлингов Соединенного королевства</Name>
      <Value>104,1694</Value>
   </Valute>
      <Valute ID="R01060">
      <NumCode>051</NumCode>
      <CharCode>AMD</CharCode>
      <Nominal>100</Nominal>
      <Name>Армянских драмов</Name>
      <Value>14,3761</Value>
   </Valute>
</ValCurs>
```

http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp XML Взял с этого ресурса.

Проблема в десериализации XML файла. Вот пример классов и вывод информации для проверки в Main.
На данный момент выдает ошибку

> InvalidOperationException: ValCurs xmlns='' was not expected.

*Уточнение*: использую .Netcore 3.1

```
[Serializable()]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ValCurs")]
class CurrencyClass
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Valute")]
    public List<Valute> Valutes { get; set; }
}

[Serializable()]
class Valute
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ID")]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "NumCode")]
    public string NumCode { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "CharCode")]
    public string CharCode { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Nominal")]
    public string Nominal { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var formatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DocumentClass));
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\repositivs\ConsoleApp1\CurValute.xml", FileMode.Open))
    {
        var currencyTest = (CurrencyClass)formatter.Deserialize(fs);
        Console.WriteLine("Объект десериализован");
        foreach (Valute valute in currencyTest.Valutes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ID: {0}", valute.ID[0]);
            Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} ", valute.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Nominal: {0}", valute.Nominal);
            Console.WriteLine("Value: {0} ", valute.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Помимо этого была попытка использовать XmlReader, попытка неудачная.

Comment: ни примера XML, ни текста ошибки, и не ясно причем тут вообще БД. По сути тут не с чем помогать. Добавьте нужную информацию в вопрос и уберите ненужную.

Comment: Я оставил ссылку на xml файл. БД нужна для хранения иногда поступающих и изменяющихся данных из этого же XML файла  http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp. А с ошибкой действительно я прокололся, признаю.

Comment: Вопросы должны быть самосостаточными, чтобы были полезны не только вам, но и будушим читателям. Поэтому никаких ссылок никуда не надо, указывайте все в вопросе. Также как вы будете хранить информацию не относится к вопросу, я так понял у вас проблема с разбором XML, потому информация о БД тут никак не пригодится и только отвлекает от вашей проблемы. Подробнее о том, как задать хороший вопрос, можно почитать [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Спасибо за критику, я исправлюсь.

Comment: Укажите также версию .NET, что испольуете. В некоторых версиях есть ошибки с сериализацией в XML

Comment: Ваш вопрос никак не касается Code First и sql, поэтому не пишите лишнее и не ставьте нерелевантные метки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Открываем первый попавшийся [сервис для конвертации](https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/) XML в C# классы, копируем туда ваш XML, получаем на выходе

```
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Valute")]
    public class Valute
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "NumCode")]
        public string NumCode { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "CharCode")]
        public string CharCode { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Nominal")]
        public string Nominal { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Value")]
        public string Value { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ID")]
        public string ID { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "ValCurs")]
    public class ValCurs
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Valute")]
        public List<Valute> Valute { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Date")]
        public string Date { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Можно ещё в студии использовать PasteSpecial->XML as classes, там будет что то похожее, только чуть более многословное.

2.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8; // для кирилицы

            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ValCurs));
            using var reader = new StringReader(xml);

            var obj = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as ValCurs;
            Console.WriteLine($"{obj.Date} | {obj.Name}");
            foreach (var v in obj.Valute) 
                Console.WriteLine($"{v.ID} | {v.Name} | {v.Nominal} | {v.NumCode} | {v.Value}");
        }
```

Сама строка

```
        static string xml = 
@"<ValCurs Date=""01.05.2021"" name=""Foreign Currency Market"">
   <Valute ID=""R01010"">
      <NumCode>036</NumCode>
      <CharCode>AUD</CharCode>
      <Nominal>1</Nominal>
      <Name>Австралийский доллар</Name>
      <Value>58,1546</Value>
   </Valute>
   <Valute ID=""R01020A"">
      <NumCode>944</NumCode>
      <CharCode>AZN</CharCode>
      <Nominal>1</Nominal>
      <Name>Азербайджанский манат</Name>
      <Value>44,0524</Value>
   </Valute>
      <Valute ID=""R01035"">
      <NumCode>826</NumCode>
      <CharCode>GBP</CharCode>
      <Nominal>1</Nominal>
      <Name>Фунт стерлингов Соединенного королевства</Name>
      <Value>104,1694</Value>
   </Valute>
      <Valute ID=""R01060"">
      <NumCode>051</NumCode>
      <CharCode>AMD</CharCode>
      <Nominal>100</Nominal>
      <Name>Армянских драмов</Name>
      <Value>14,3761</Value>
   </Valute>
</ValCurs>";
    }
```

3. 

[image: ...]